# How to change link when clicking/copying like Facebooks Messenger chat?

Tags: javascript, facebook, click, copy, href

On Facebooks desktop site when using the messenger they seem to change the all outgoing links in the chat when you click or copy them.

The link they change to is something like:
**http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstore.steampowered.com%2**

*(this original link here being http://store.steampowered.com/ for example)*

Yet when previewing the link by hovering over it, it shows the original link.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is of course to track outgoing clicks. The solution is simple and quite sneaky. Personally I feel it's somewhat morally questionable. Your link preview when hovering does indeed show the original link, so you may gladly copy the link thinking you can paste it somewhere else and have the original, but instead you get Facebooks version.

Perhaps this is something that browsers should not allow?

In any case, this is solved with simple JavaScript.

### For the click part:

At the event of a click you swap the link to the new one and let the event pass through unhindered, so the link changed before you navigate to it.

Before finishing through the end of the listener of the event, you set a timeout function with a reasonable value - Facebook uses 100 ms. This resets the link to the original.

### For the copy part

Here you listen for a mousedown event and check that the `event.button == 2` (right mouse button). When triggered, swap the link like above, but don't set a timeout.

Instead you listen for mouseout, and on that event you reset the link back to the original value.

### In code using jQuery, assuming HTML with an anchor tag:

```
var anchor = $('a');
var sneakyLink = 'http://www.altavista.com';
var prevLink = anchor[0].href;

anchor.on('click',function(e){
    anchor[0].href = sneakyLink;
    setTimeout(function(){
        anchor[0].href=prevLink;
    },100);
    return true;
});

anchor.on('mousedown',function(e){
    if(e.button == 2) {        
        anchor[0].href = sneakyLink;
    }    
});

anchor.on('mouseout',function(e){
    anchor[0].href = prevLink;
});
```

JSFiddle demo with the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/657FN/1/